# How to interpret results from atos symbolication command

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicate

I'm using the atos command to symbolicate crash logs.

I have this crash stack :

```
0   MyApp                               0x001c4389 MyApp + 1848201
1   MyApp                               0x001c49f1 MyApp + 1849841
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f1f7ed _sigtramp + 48
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f1520f pthread_kill + 54
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33f0e29f abort + 94
5   MyApp                               0x00021843 MyApp + 133187
6   MyApp                               0x00005569 MyApp + 17769
7   MyApp                               0x00022b9b MyApp + 138139
8   MyApp                               0x0000637b MyApp + 21371
```

Let's symbolicate the line 6 :

```
atos -arch armv7 -o MyApp.app/MyApp 0x00005569
=> -[MyAppCoreDataManager persistentStoreCoordinatorForUpdate] (in MyApp) (MyAppCoreDataManager.m:176)
```

Perfect, but line 5 :

```
atos -arch armv7 -o Popcarte.app/Popcarte 0x00021843
=> 0x00021843 (in MyApp) + 47
```

I think it references a @synthesize, but i'm not sure, and I would like to know which one.

Is there a way to know more about this result ?